# Monitor Network Activity of Applications and Users from the Command Line (like Top does for processor)

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

Is there a linux command, that works like "top" (like top does for monitoring processor utilization), but shows network activity of users and applications realtime?

I want something that shows everything going on, where I don't have to specify each and everything to get an overview. Anything like this?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html

Answer (score 3):

[Iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) is pretty nice for live overviews, [vnstat](http://humdi.net/vnstat/) is a lightweight alternative for every-now-and-then statistics.

Answer (score 2):

[pktstat](http://www.adaptive-enterprises.com.au/~d/software/pktstat/) is a great cmdline utility; shows url paths etc

[tcptrack](http://www.rhythm.cx/~steve/devel/tcptrack/) is also good.

[iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) is also okay.

Answer (score 1):

The best one I know of is [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/news.php), but it display stats via a web interface on port 3000. Not sure if there's one that runs just via a terminal.